# Listing All Files From Dir and First FIle Listed Twice WIth PHP

Tags: php

I am listing all the files in a dir with php but the first file is being listed twice.

Also there was a `%20` being added to the url when the link was clicked. It appeared right before the username when being added to the url path to download and then it went away without any changes being made to my script.

Any ideas what would cause this type of behavior?

```
<?php
$directory = 'downloads/username';

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));

while($it->valid()) {

    if (!$it->isDot()) {
?>
       <a href="https://www.example.com/site-dev/downloads/<?php echo $current_user->display_name . '/' . $it->getSubPathName() . '">'?>
       <?php echo $it->getSubPathName() . "</a><br>";
        // echo 'SubPath:     ' . $it->getSubPath() . "<br>";
        // echo 'Key:         ' . $it->key() . "\n\n";
    }

    $it->next();
}
?>
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the duplicate file names. Is this the only code within the file? Are you sure there aren't any hidden files within that directory? Can you show us the output of `ls` within that folder?

Comment: The file that is being listed twice was a file that iI cancelled uploading then went back an uploaded a minute later. Do you think its somehow showing that file? But when it list it out it literally is calling it by the same name.

Comment: and yes there is other code on the page. It is a wordpress template file I am editing.

Comment: It's possible that it was part of the upload. Similar to when you download files from chrome, while it's downloading you see hidden files named the same but ending with `.part`, this is just speculation though. Are you setting the temporary directory to `'downloads/username'` by any chance? (Check `sys_get_temp_dir()`).

Comment: I have been hacking my way through this for 2 hours. I am not sure even what your asking me. Basically I am listing all the files from the dir with the username logged in.  I was thinking I need to add something to my code to handle if the user does not have a folder created so when I do $directory = 'downloads/' . $current_user->display_name;  There is no error if it does not exist. Do you think this is good like that? Or do I need to add more error handling?

Comment: Here is what I get when I echo tmp dir wuno-small-logo.ai
/tmp/Tux7kAIS3 wuno-small-logo.ai
/tmp/TuxyEXg8D front.ai
/tmp/TuxURuPne Wuno-final-logo-2.ai
/tmp/Tux0DfoDO Wuno-final-logo.ai
/tmp/TuxyosXSo back.ai
/tmp/TuxqNRw8Y

Comment: Is that from the command prompt/terminal or from PHP? PHP will throw an `UnexpectedValueException` if the directory doesn't exist so wrapping it in try/catch should suffice.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton for your help. I got it fixed up. That was from php my code outputs that to the browser. weird thing is when I ssh in and ls -a i only see 5 files but my scripts shows me 6 still